# Understanding Random Variable definition for Indicator variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to understand the definition of Random Variable against an example here. This is a very basic question and I can intuitively understand this, but I somewhere feel I have not put it down to the last nail.

Source: [Source section 1.2.1 from Amir Dembo's notes, Stanford University]

Definition: We say a mapping $X:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ between two measurable spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $(\mathcal{R},\mathcal{B})$ is called a $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$-valued Random Variable (R.V.) if $X^{-1}(B):=\{\omega:X(\omega)\in B\}\in\mathcal{F}$, $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Example: Now looking at Example 1.2.4 from the same source. For any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ the function $I_A(\omega)=\begin{cases}1, \omega \in A\\ 0, \omega\notin A\end{cases}$ is a R.V. Indeed, $\{\omega: I_A(\omega)\in B\}$ is for any $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ one of the four sets $\emptyset, A, A^c$, or $\Omega$ (depending on whether $0\in B$ or not and whether $1 \in B$ or not), all of whom are in $\mathcal{F}$. We call such R.V. also an indicator function.

Questions: I am trying to relate this example with the exact definition of R.V. as stated above. Concretely, I want a crisp one-to-one correspondence between all the variables in the definition from the example - what are $X, \Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}$ in our example? A detailed example is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ in definition $\sim$ $I_A:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ in example. This for a fixed $A\in\mathcal F$.
- $\Omega$ in definition $\sim$ $\Omega$ in example.
- $\mathcal F$ in definition $\sim$ $\mathcal F$ in example.
- $\mathcal B$ in definition is not explicitly stated in example but is also $\mathcal B$ there.

---

So actually only the first bullet has some relevance.

Concerning the fourth bullet it is enough to observe that $I_A^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid I_A(\omega)\in B\}\in\mathcal F$ for **every** $B\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Then of course it is true for every $B\in\mathcal B$.

In definition it is requested that: $$X^{-1}(\mathcal B)=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal B\}\subseteq\mathcal F$$

In example it is observed that: $$I_A^{-1}(\mathcal B)=\{I_A^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal B\}\subseteq\{I_A^{-1}(B)\mid B\subseteq\mathbb R\}=\{\varnothing,A,A^{\complement},\Omega\}\subseteq\mathcal F$$

So the request is fulfilled and $I_A$ can be marked as random variable.